# Assignment of String values to TextViews in Android Programing?

Tags: android, string, listview, textview

I want to assign the values of the string t and string b to the two TextView declared in R.layout.news_01story 
Can this be done? Help needed!

The bellow method takes us to a new Layout when we click an item in a ListView-->

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        RowData row = adapter.getItem(position);
        String t = row.mTitle;
        String b = row.mDescription;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_01story,null);
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.show();
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
....
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_01story,null);
TextView textView1 = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id....);
textView.setText(t);
TextView textView2 = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id....);
textView.setText(b);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1)).setText(t);
((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2)).setText(b);
```